# npm package missing folders

Tags: javascript, npm, npm-install

I've created an published a private npm package successfully. Here is the file structure:

```
Library.Util
|
|__src
   |
   |__helper
      |
      |__typeChecker.js
|
|__index.js
|
|__package.json
```

When I install this package on another project, the entire file structure is different:

```
Library.Util
|
|__index.js
|
|__package.json
```

I have tried changing my `main` in `package.json`, and importing `typeChecker.js` into the `index.js` file, but that didn't seem to do it. Additionally, I confirmed that none of `typeChecker.js` is not in my `.gitignore` file. Wanted to know if anyone had an idea of what was going on.

Comment: Do you have an `.npmignore` file that might be ignoring your `src` directory?

Comment: No, I don't have an `.npmignore` file

Comment: Have you verified that the src folder exists in the npm repo? is there a script copying your src to dst folders on build ..?

Answer (score 0):

We are facing the same issue, and are missing the `src/` sub-directory when running a global install of an NPM package from our private NPM registry.

There is nothing referenced in the `.npmignore` or `.gitignore` files, and we are even explicitly referencing the `src/` sub-directory in `files` block in the `package.json`:

```
{
...
  "main": "./bin/cli.js",
  "bin": {
    "app_name": "./bin/cli.js"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/cli.js"
  },
  "files": [
    "bin",
    "test",
    "src",
    "package.json"
  ],
...
}
```

Interestingly the install also fails to install the `test` sub-directory, and moving the entry point to the `src/` sub-directory results in it failing to install at all with the following error:

```
ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '...node_modules/@private_registry/app_name/src/cli.js
```